# C++ if one thread writes toggles a bool once done, is it safe to read that bool in a loop in a single other thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I am building a very simple program as an exercise.

The idea is to compute the total size of a directory by recursively iterating over all its contents, and summing the sizes of all files contained in the directory (and its subdirectories).

To show to a user that the program is still working, this computation is performed on another thread, while the main thread prints a dot `.` once every second.

Now the main thread of course needs to know when it should stop printing dots and can look up a result.
It is possible to use e.g. a `std::atomic<bool> done(false);` and pass this to the thread that will perform the computation, which will set it to `true` once it is finished. But I am wondering if in this simple case (one thread writes once completed, one thread reads periodically until nonzero) it is necessary to use atomic data types for this. Obviously if *multiple* threads might write to it, it needs to be protected. But in this case, there's only one writing thread and one reading thread.

Is it necessary to use an atomic data type here, or is it overkill and could a normal data type be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is necessary.  The rule is that if two threads could potentially be accessing the same memory at the same time, and at least one of the threads is a writer, then you have a data race.  Any execution of a program with a data race has undefined behavior.

Relevant quotes from the C++14 standard:

1.10/23

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

1.10/6

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one accesses or modifies the same memory location.

Comment: I would expect the writing/reading of a primitive `int` or `bool` to be atomic. Why is this not the case? (Or is it one of those 'can not assume to be' things?)

In any case, thank you for quoting the relevant sections from the standard. This is the most clear answer so far :-).

Comment: @Qqwy: I believe the only standard way to create an atomic object is by declaring it to have type `std::atomic<T>` or `std::atomic_flag`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's necessary.

The issue is that the different cores of the processor can have different views of the "same" data, notably data that's been cached within the CPU. The `atomic` part ensures that these caches are properly flushed so that you can safely do what you are trying to do.

Otherwise, it's quite possible that the other thread will never actually see the flag change from the first thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is necessary. Otherwise it is not guaranteed that changes to the `bool` in one thread will be observable in the other thread. In fact, if the compiler sees that the `bool` variable is, apparently, not ever used again in the execution thread that sets it, it might completely optimize away the code that sets the value of the `bool`.

Comment: If the bool is marked `volatile` the compiler cannot optimize any access away.

Comment: Wow. So even if I pass the bool as a reference to the thread, the compiler might rewrite my code to something that will never see the value change?

Comment: If the compiler sees that after the bool value is set it is never used again by the execution thread, the compiler can legally optimize the whole thing away. The fact that at some earlier point in time the execution thread constructed an instance of a class named `std::thread`, passing a reference or a pointer to this bool doesn't change. The C++ compiler has no knowledge of the fact that constructing an instance of a class called `std::thread` ends up creating a new execution thread. That's a function of the C++ library.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Unlike the asker of the question you linked. I don't misunderstand what `volatile` does. I don't claim access doesn't need synchronization, I claim compilers don't preform problematic optimizations on `volatile ` objects.

Comment: @StoryTeller while your comment is technically correct it doesn't help op. And can be easily misunderstood to that effect, in my opinion.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe My comment is about Sam's statement that the compiler can optimize away the access. It absolutely does help the OP avoid *that*.

Comment: @StoryTeller - But it doesn't help. `volatile` has nothing to do with threading, it is about memory mapped hardware. If the threads run on separate CPUs, they might not sees each others `volatile` variables, even if the reads and writes are performed by the hardware. With atomic they do.

Comment: @BoPersson - How many times must I repeat myself? I don't claim `volatile` replaces proper synchronization constructs. I claim it prevents problematic compiler optimizations.

Comment: How much slower reading an atomic variable will be compared to a non atomic variable?

Comment: Anything stopping you, @RonyTesler, from writing a few quick benchmark to measure the difference on your actual hardware/software?

Comment: So if I use atomic I don't need to use volatile?